# java dxa-2.2 Cannot create a default CIL cache configuration, fallback to default configuration

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa2.2

Could someone please help me on below error how to fix it.

```
22:45:09.431 [restartedMain] DEBUG c.s.w.c.c.c.i.BaseClientConfigurationLoader - Loaded Cache configuration: '{CacheExpirationDuration=600, ServiceAvailabilityCheck=false, CachePassword=, CacheEnabled=true, CacheClientId=, CacheUri=, CacheProviderClass=, ServiceUri=, CacheConnectionTimeout=}'
22:45:09.431 [restartedMain] WARN  c.s.d.c.DefaultNamedCacheProvider - Config URI for Cache Provider is empty, using default fallback option
22:45:09.433 [restartedMain] INFO  org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration - Loading Ehcache XML configuration from file:/C:/Users/nnarvaria/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sdl.delivery/udp-discovery-client-lightweight/11.1.0-1063/dd46914fbcb3bffed574be589ebba69cb5a5eca1/udp-discovery-client-lightweight-11.1.0-1063.jar!/ehcache-default.xml.
22:45:09.461 [restartedMain] WARN  c.s.d.c.DefaultNamedCacheProvider - Cannot create a default CIL cache configuration, fallback to default configuration
com.sdl.web.client.configuration.api.ConfigurationException: Cannot load 'default' template from 
    at com.sdl.dxa.caching.DefaultNamedCacheProvider.buildConfigCacheConfiguration(DefaultNamedCacheProvider.java:191)
    at com.sdl.dxa.caching.DefaultNamedCacheProvider.buildDefaultCilCacheConfiguration(DefaultNamedCacheProvider.java:162)
    at com.sdl.dxa.caching.DefaultNamedCacheProvider.buildDefaultCacheConfiguration(DefaultNamedCacheProvider.java:144)
    at com.sdl.dxa.caching.DefaultNamedCacheProvider.getCache(DefaultNamedCacheProvider.java:108)
    at com.sdl.dxa.caching.DefaultNamedCacheProvider.getCache(DefaultNamedCacheProvider.java:123)
    at com.sdl.dxa.caching.wrapper.SimpleCacheWrapper.getCache(SimpleCacheWrapper.java:68)
    at com.sdl.dxa.caching.wrapper.SimpleCacheWrapper.init(SimpleCacheWrapper.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
```

I have added following properties on dxa.properties file

```
dxa.caching.disabled.caches=
dxa.caching.required.caches=

dxa.caching.configuration=dxa-ehcache.xml
```

and dxa-ehcache.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.ehcache.org/v3"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.1.xsd">

    <heap-store>
        <max-object-graph-size>100000</max-object-graph-size>
    </heap-store>

    <cache-template name="default">
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">300</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <resources>
            <heap unit="entries">10000</heap>
        </resources>
    </cache-template>

    <cache alias="defaultCache" uses-template="default"/>

    <cache alias="pageModels" uses-template="default"/>
    <cache alias="entityModels" uses-template="default"/>
    <cache alias="staticContentItems" uses-template="default"/>
    <cache alias="resolvedLinks" uses-template="default"/>
    <cache alias="queryCache" uses-template="default"/>
    <cache alias="output" uses-template="default"/>
    <cache alias="failures" uses-template="default"/>

    <cache alias="com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.ContentServiceCapability" uses-template="default">
        <key-type>java.io.Serializable</key-type>
        <value-type>com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.ContentServiceCapability</value-type>
    </cache>
    <cache alias="com.sdl.context.api.ContextMap" uses-template="default">
        <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
        <value-type>com.sdl.context.api.ContextMap</value-type>
    </cache>

    <cache alias="com.sdl.context.api.ContextVocabulary" uses-template="default">
        <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
        <value-type>com.sdl.context.api.ContextVocabulary</value-type>
    </cache>

    <cache alias="com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.ContextServiceCapability" uses-template="default">
        <key-type>java.io.Serializable</key-type>
        <value-type>com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.ContextServiceCapability</value-type>
    </cache>
    <cache alias="com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationResource" uses-template="default">
        <key-type>java.io.Serializable</key-type>
        <value-type>com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationResource</value-type>
    </cache>

    <cache alias="java.io.Serializable" uses-template="default">
        <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
        <value-type>java.io.Serializable</value-type>
    </cache>
</config>
```

any help/suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your ehcache.xml. Is there a reason why you've choosen to use heap unit entries and not a memsize (like MB)? Is your jvm max size not exceeded after a while?

Answer (score 1):

After investigating I found out udp-discovery-client-lightweight:11.1.0-1063 api is trying to find default ehcache file with name : **ehcache-default.xml**.

In order to fix exception on console, i have **renamed dxa-ehcache.xml to ehcache-default.xml**

and on dxa.properties also updated the reference for key **dxa.caching.configuration**

from **dxa-ehcache.xml** to **ehcache-default.xml**

which is now

```
dxa.caching.configuration=ehcache-default.xml
```